# Getting "no loop for break/next, jumping to top level" error despite for loop completing normally

Tags: r, for-loop

I keep getting the following error:
`Error in xxx : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level`

Code below:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(engine_categories)){
    col <- max.col(replace(engine_categories[i,2:ncols],max.col(engine_categories[i,2:ncols],"first"), -Inf),"first")
    col <- col + 1
    column_num2 <- append(column_num2,col)
  }
```

I took the time to debug the for loop and everything seems to be working fine. I stepped through, i iterates as expected and the loop exits at the value I would expect it to. However, it still throws the error upon competing the loop.

Comment: You need to provide more details if the dupe-target does not solve your problem.